# How many visitors from a specific country visit a specific destination?

Tags: travel

In my case I want to know how many people from Argentina visit Orlando.

I found several sources (UN DATA,UNWTO) that distribute information which specify the country of origin and country of destination. But I need city-level granularity for the destination location.

Comment: Try contacting the Orlando tourism bureau. https://orlandotouristinformationbureau.com/ https://www.visitorlando.com/